# VBA Excel Break Points and Stop do not work

Tags: vba, excel

Any idea why inserting break points and stop no longer stops my vba code from running?

The code runs ok all the way to the end (I tested it) but ignores break points and Stop.

Also step into just makes the code run in it's entirety, ignoring break points and stops.

When I close the workbook where the issue seems to originate from the same issue occurs in other macro workbooks.

if I completely close excel and re-open it with a normally working macro workbook the issue doesn't occur until I re-open the problem work book.

I added breakpoints on:

```
TotP1 = 0
```

of the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Country As String
Private Measure As String
Private P1 As String
Private P2 As String
Private TotP1 As Double
Private TotP2 As Double


Sub VennDisplayIt()

Dim SI() As String
Dim SICount As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim OSh As Worksheet
Dim BrandListBox As Object
Dim VennGroup As Shape

TotP1 = 0
TotP2 = 0


Set OSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Venn")

Set BrandListBox = OSh.OLEObjects("BrandListBox").Object

ReDim SI(2, 0)

For x = 0 To BrandListBox.ListCount - 1

    If BrandListBox.Selected(x) = True Then
        'If UBound(SI) < 4 Then
            ReDim Preserve SI(2, UBound(SI, 2) + 1)

            SI(1, UBound(SI, 2)) = BrandListBox.List(x)
            SI(2, UBound(SI, 2)) = x + 1
        'End If

    End If

Next x


If UBound(SI, 2) < 2 Then
    BrandListBox.Selected(BrandListBox.ListIndex) = True
    Exit Sub
ElseIf UBound(SI, 2) > 4 Then
    BrandListBox.Selected(BrandListBox.ListIndex) = False
    Exit Sub
End If

For x = 1 To UBound(SI, 2)
    OSh.Range("o8").Offset(x, 0).Value = SI(1, x)
    OSh.Range("o8").Offset(x + 5, 0).Value = SI(1, x)
Next x

For x = UBound(SI, 2) + 1 To 4
    OSh.Range("o8").Offset(x, 0).Value = ""
    OSh.Range("o8").Offset(x + 5, 0).Value = ""
Next x


SICount = UBound(SI, 2)

For x = 1 To OSh.Shapes.Count
    If Right(OSh.Shapes(x).Name, 5) = "Group" Then
    If LCase(OSh.Shapes(x).Name) = SICount & "waygroup" Then
        Set VennGroup = OSh.Shapes(x)
        OSh.Shapes(x).Visible = True
    Else
        OSh.Shapes(x).Visible = False
    End If
    End If

Next x

For x = 1 To SICount

    VennGroup.GroupItems.Item(SICount & "WayBrand" & x).DrawingObject.Text = SI(1, x)

Next x


Country = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Venn").Range("D4").Value
Measure = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Venn").Range("E32").Value
P2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Venn").Range("E31").Value
P1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Selections").Range("B5").Value


End Sub
```

Comment: Could you show the code and where the breakpoints are placed?

Comment: I just added the code.

Comment: I ran your code with a breakpoint on `TotP1 = 0` and it broke there exactly as it should. So my guess is that there is indeed something corrupted in that workbook.

Comment: @ExcelHero Ithink you may be right. It's crashed a few time recently. I'm ging to try and re-create it in a new workbook. I get the same probelm on two different machines so it seems to be the file rather than excel settings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've never heard of `Stop` not working, but I've heard about and experienced the breakpoint thing many times. When you compile VBA, it creates a p-code, which is used by the interpreter. You have the VBA syntax layer that you can see and the p-code layer that you can't see. When breakpoints stop working, it's because the p-code was corrupted. I don't know how or why it happened, but it did.

The fix is to export, remove, and reimport all of your modules. Exporting them creates a .bas file (plain text, really). When you re-import, the p-code is regenerated from scratch.  If you have more than a couple of modules, get CodeCleaner (free add-in) and it will export and reimport automatically.

Comment: Not only have I never experienced `Stop` (as written in the code) not working, but whenever I'm having the (frequent) issue of breakpoints not breaking execution and/or code updates not showing on execution, adding a single `Stop` resolves it instantaneously. Since there is no real written `Stop` in @OliverHumphreys code, I wonder if he was actually talking about `Stop` or thinking about `F9` breakpoints / conditional breakpoints.

Comment: "Stop" is a command that is used to break the code in that location instead of creating a break-point.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Code is running all the way through without stopping at breakpoints or Stop lines. Step into runs the whole routine (F8=F5).

Comment: I'm not having any luck with exporting modules, even after re-importing into a new workbook.  Stop ain't working.

Comment: Exporting and reimporting did not work for me. For whatever reason, it turned out a reboot fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

If one of the settings is unchecked then breakpoints will not work. "File/options/Current database/Application options/use access special keys" should be checked

Answer (score 4):

Just to 'second' Tibo's comment: I had a problem where I had a form with about 5 different subroutines.  One of them (attached to a button event) would not stop when I set a breakpoint.  in 10 years of VBA writing, I've never seen that happen.  Interestingly, breakpoints worked on all of the other subroutines in that form.  After much head-scratching and searching, I came upon this post and Tibo's comment.  I added a "Stop" command to the affected subroutine, ran the procedure (it stopped as it should have) and then breakpoints began working again!  Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If the breakpoints are in your code, then the code should stop running as soon as it hits that line. Possible causes of your problem:

a) The code never gets to the Breakpoint. 
Seems highly unlikely seeing as you're breaking on the first line of your code. Maybe step through the sub (F8) just to check it's running as it should.

b) Your breakpoints have been wiped. Any line with a breakpoint should display as highlighted in red on your IDE. Your breakpoints can easily be wiped through, e.g. closing and opening the workbook (a screenshot would be really useful).

c) your workbook is broken in some way. It would be unlikely to break something as fundamental as stopping at breakpoints and still function normally. Are you sure your code is actually running?

Comment: Hi, It looks like it's C). I can't step through the code as that's part of the problem. however my break points are definitely in place and highlighted in red. the code is definitely running as I put a test right at the end to modify a cell and it worked. I've just transferred everything to a new workbook and it seems to be working ok for the time being.

Comment: Okay, glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the problems as described above:

- Stop and Breakpoints not working
- Single step F8 worked, but code was not highlighted in yellow

Closing VBA editor did not help

**My remedy**: close VBA editor again, save Excel-file, open editor, back to normal

I've never faced this problem for years. Today for the first time I started using watch expressions with stopping when true.

Answer (score 1):

Closing all excel windows and opening the workbook in which I was having problems again worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing a funny thing which happened to me in case it helps someone. The mistake I did was that I simply took someone's method code meant for workbook open event and pasted it on `Sheet1` excel object code area. So there was no possibility of `Workbook_Open` method getting fired ever.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Stop
    On Error Resume Next
    Call ActiveSheet.Worksheet_Activate
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

What I was supposed to do is paste this method after double clicking `ThisWorkbook` node under `Microsoft Excel Objects` in Project pane as shown below:

[image]

**Note**: Side effect of copy-pasting others code can be freaky at times.

Answer (score 0):

a) Double check that your breakpoints got disabled or not.

b) Double check that you added a conditional breakpoint or not

c) If you run your macro using C# code (using, the _Run2 command), breakpoints and stop doesn't work sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me once in a while and the following solves the problem for me every time:
Create a Sub with only the command Stop in it. Run it. Then try your routine, the breakpoints and Stop commands should now work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you do not have a named Range that matches the name of the Function or Subroutine you are calling. This will look like the Function or Subroutine is failing, but it is actually failing before the routine is ever called with an 'invalid cell reference'.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. My solution was put an error in the code and run it. After I cleared the error the breakpoints started working again. That was weird.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this problem.  Breakpoints and Stop statements were being ignored.  In my case, the problem *appeared* to be caused by the following code placed in `ThisWorkbook` in the `Open_Workbook` event:

```
With popupMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
    .OnAction = ThisWorkbook.Name & "!InsertTransactionRow(""Expense"")"
    .Caption = "Insert an expense row"
End With

With popupMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
    .OnAction = ThisWorkbook.Name & "!InsertTransactionRow(""Income"")"
    .Caption = "Insert an income row"
End With
```

Breakpoints and Stop statements within the called routine (i.e. `InsertTransactionRow` were ignored, yet there was no doubt the code was running.

I modified `ThisWorkbook!Open_Workbook` as follows:

```
With popupMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
    .OnAction = ThisWorkbook.Name & "!InsertExpenseRow"
    .Caption = "Insert an expense row"
End With

With popupMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
    .OnAction = ThisWorkbook.Name & "!InsertIncomeRow"
    .Caption = "Insert an income row"
End With
```

Now instead of calling the generic method `InsertTransactionRow` where the parameter identifies the type of transaction, I call the transaction specific method `InsertExpenseRow` or `InsertIncomeRow`, neither of which takes a parameter.  This change resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem over the last week or so - stop and break points with F9 would occur , F8 would run the code shown below - there is a lot of other code though

It occurs a lot and all I could do was exit excel and restart

My fix has been ...

Turn off background compile , Then Debug>Compile and get rid of all errors
But then I got the problem described here -
https://www.businessprogrammer.com/code-execution-has-been-interrupted/

This being a "Code Execution has been interrupted" message from VBA with no break point shown in the VBA window.  Just a stopped execution.

Note I found it when I was attempting to test with F9 etc etc so its maybe unrelated

This is fixed by closing the dialog and then pressing CTRL-Break in the VBA window

As it has been  intermittent for me - I'd be interested if this fixes the problem for others

```
Sub sleepy()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Debug.Print Now
    DoEvents
    Stop
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem too...

I was writing code to modify a sheet level formula in a .xlsx file.
I did a lot of code and it worked, including breakpoints.
Later, satisfied, I tried to save it and it alerted me to save as .xlsm file, of course.

I did it and, boom, no more breakpoints were hit and F9 could not recalculate the cells with formulas that depended on this VBA code.
I closed and reopened several times, moved code between modules, lost several minutes and came here, to no avail.

Later, I remembered to check at Macro security... it was OK; but anyway I removed all macro access, as figure is showing (I konw, I know, it is in Portuguese, but at same place in English version...), saved file, and reapplied it, granted all access, and it worked. Now it is working perfectly.

Go figure...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also note that Stop won't work if the VBA Project is Protected.

Unlocking a Protected VBA Project will allow Stop to work while the workbook is open, but it won't work the next time the workbook is opened unless Protection is removed entirely.

Answer (score -1):

Not just me then!  On a few occasions the yellow hi-lite stops a few lines beyond the breakpoint!  I guess the code is running so fast it can't stop in time. :)  As suggested above, I find adding "stops" here and there and also exporting & re-importing helps too.

Comment: This should probably be a comment instead of an answer, since you're just commiserating with the OP and supporting other answers.

Comment: Thanks Shader - I've not quite got the hang of this forum - I'll remember that in future.

Answer (score -2):

I been writing code in VBA for many years but today I  came across this problem for the first time. None of the solutions I found on the web worked but here's something simply you can use instead of Stop:

ErrCatch = 1 / 0

Still doesn't solve the breakpoints not working though...

Answer (score -2):

I went int my vba code, added an enter (new blank line), then ran it again.
Voila! It ran the code and stopped at the breakpoint!